# how to redirect the login page based on the url in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular7, angular8

Actually I have two different login page for user and admin. I am differentiating the admin login and user login by login url.

Like;

user login: http://localhost:4200/userlogin

admin login: http://localhost:4200/adminlogin

If it is ***/userlogin***  then I have to redirect to userLogin component

If it is ***/adminlogin***  then I have to redirect to adminLogin component

Is there any way for doing this? If yes can anybody suggest me the ways to do this?

Comment: You can simply define routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define angular routes and this should work.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'userlogin', component: UserLoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'adminlogin', component: AdminLoginComponent
  },
  ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand as soon as someone logs in, you check for the type of user most probably in the backend and sending the response back to the `http` call, there you can simply check and use Angular `Router` Service to redirect:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

login() {
     // your api call response must be having some logic to differentiate between user and admin
     if(user.type === 'admin') {
         this.router.navigate(['/adminlogin']);
        } else if(user.type === 'user') {
        this.router.navigate(['/userlogin']);
        } 

}
```